# group By Contact information by customerID

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to to remove the duplicated from my SQL statement Customer id ,firstname and lastName I want to be able group by customerID and Remove the duplicated Customer id form,firstname and lastName From Final output

```
SELECT customers.customerid, 
       customers.title, 
       customers.firstname, 
       customers.lastname, 
       customers.postion, 
       company.companyname, 
       (SELECT label.labelcontacttype 
        FROM   label 
        WHERE  label.labelcontacttypeid = 
       customer_contacts.labelcontacttypeid)AS 
       contactType, 
       customer_contacts.contactdetails, 
       customer_contacts.status, 
       customer_contacts.notes 
FROM   customers 
       INNER JOIN customer_company 
               ON customers.customerid = customer_company.customerid 
       INNER JOIN company 
               ON customer_company.companyid = company.companyid 
       INNER JOIN customer_contacts 
               ON customers.customerid = customer_contacts.customerid
```

Current output

```
15  Mr  Mike Smith Web Developer    compudata   Email   email@email.com 1   dvv  
15  Mr  Mike Smith Web Developer    compudata   Phone   111-111-1111    1   ex:2222
```

Comment: What's your question?  What are the inputs?  What's not working?

Comment: The reason for the dups is due to the `contacttype` being different with different values, which one do you want to display?  Or how do you want the data displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really not very clear what you are trying to do, but if you only want the customerid, title, firstname and lastname to appear once, then you can use:

```
select 
  case when rn = 1 then customerid else '' end customerid,
  case when rn = 1 then title else '' end title,
  case when rn = 1 then firstname else '' end firstname,
  case when rn = 1 then lastname else '' end lastname,
  postion,
  companyname,
  contactType,
  contactdetails, 
  status, 
  notes
from
(
  SELECT cast(customers.customerid as varchar(20)) customerid, 
         customers.title, 
         customers.firstname, 
         customers.lastname, 
         customers.postion, 
         company.companyname, 
         (SELECT label.labelcontacttype 
          FROM   label 
          WHERE  label.labelcontacttypeid = 
         customer_contacts.labelcontacttypeid)AS contactType, 
         customer_contacts.contactdetails, 
         customer_contacts.status, 
         customer_contacts.notes ,
         row_number() over(order by customers.customerid) rn
  FROM   customers 
         INNER JOIN customer_company 
                 ON customers.customerid = customer_company.customerid 
         INNER JOIN company 
                 ON customer_company.companyid = company.companyid 
         INNER JOIN customer_contacts 
                 ON customers.customerid = customer_contacts.customerid 
) src
```